# Gnome3.6.2 - empathy chats do not appear in the notification bar after a while in fedora 18

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, notifications, empathy

I am using fedora 18 with Gnome 3.6.2 and I've updated empathy to the latest version (Empathy 3.6.4) yesterday. it works fine at first, but after a while, the notification bar which is at the down part of the screen disappears and no notifications will be shown there anymore. so for new conversations, I hear the sound notification for the message which is received, but because no pop up window is shown, I can't find out who has sent the message and I miss them.

I think the problem is not because of empathy and the main problem is the notification bar which is disappeared. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

usually updating the system solves problems like this.

try : `yum update` and check if it solves or not.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 18 is past end of life, no more updates or bug fixes are forthcomming. Upgrade to current Fedora 20. Read and follow the update notes carefully, there have been bad glitches with `fedup` (mostly that the updated system boots into the old system, not into updating; they *should* be ironed out by now), and keep a machine connected to the 'net at hand for googling solutions in case the update fails.